# How to compare two spinner items?

Tags: android-spinner

i have created a ticket reservation app in which following data will be saved about passenger.
1) passenger name
2) passenger phone number
3) city from which passenger will go
4) city to which passenger will go

my code is as follows

```
public class TicketReservationView extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static Database theDatabase;
private EditText etName,etContact;
private Spinner spFrom,spTo;
private Button bSave,bShowSms;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ticket_reservation_view);

    etName    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassengerName);
    etContact = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etContactNo);

    spFrom = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spFrom);
    spTo   = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spTo);

    bSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSave);
    bSave.setOnClickListener(this);

    bShowSms = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bShowSms);
    bShowSms.setOnClickListener(this);      

    db = theDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
    theDatabase.insert_city_data(db);
    db.close();

    loadData();


private  void loadData()
{
    db=theDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] cities=theDatabase.getCitiesData(db);

    ArrayAdapter<String> fromAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TicketReservationView.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cities);
    fromAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spFrom.setAdapter(fromAdapter);

    spTo.setAdapter(fromAdapter);
    db.close();
}
private String[] fillData()
{
    String[] data= new String[4];

    data[0] = etName.getText().toString();
    data[1] = etContact.getText().toString();
    data[2] = (String)spFrom.getSelectedItem();
    data[3] = (String)spTo.getSelectedItem();

    return data;
}


switch(view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.bSave:
        db = theDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
        boolean isPassengerExist = theDatabase.getPassengerExistance(db,etContact.getText().toString());
        db.close();
        if(!isPassengerExist)
        {
            String[] data = fillData();
            db = theDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
            theDatabase.insert_ticket_data(data,db);
            showToast("Data saved Successfully");
            db.close();
        }
        else
        {


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Already Exist!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        break;
```

now the problem is that if the FROM city and TO city are same, it should display a toast that CITY NAMES ARE SAME.
i have tried following code

```
if(spFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(spTo.getSelectedItem()))

{
      toast: "city names are same"
```

}

but it does not work for me

Comment: Can you verify that `String#equals` is called and that the two selections are indeed equal?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if(spFrom.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(spTo.getSelectedItem().toString())){
  Toast.makeText(this,"city names are same",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This will work